# How to save output data for many iterations in Netlogo

Tags: iteration, export-to-csv, netlogo

I save data for the simulation as csv files using: File>Export>Export World which works for 1 iteration. I would like to run my model for 1000 simulations (and more) and save data at every iteration. Because at every run, the output is different. I worked through an example in BehaviourSpace but my output data is not detailed as the one I get using File>Export>Export World. I have also tried from the csv example and the output for the all the turtles-own (infected?, infected2?, infected3?, susceptible?) were the same.

In BehaviourSpace, under the option of Measure runs using these reporters, I would like to count turtles-own like infected?, infected1? but when I do that I get an error; **Experiment aborted due to syntax error: You can't use INFECTED? in an observer context, because INFECTED? is turtle-only.**

My question is how to track population of the infected, infected2 and infected3 as csv files for many iterations without having to do it manually (attached is my code). Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
globals
[
  sink-patches 
  time1 
  time2 
  signs  
  timeA 
  prob1 
  prob2 
 ]

breed [popns popn] ;;T defines the name of a single member of the breed.
breed [ppls ppl]
popns-own
[
  infected?    
  infected2?     
  infected3?   
  susceptible?    
  infected-time
  infection2-time 
]
;; setup procedures
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-globals
  setup-people
  reset-ticks ; Resets the tick counter to zero, sets up all plots, then updates all plots.
end
to setup-globals
  set signs 13 
  set timeA signs + time1 
  set prob1 25
  set prob2 50
end
to setup-patches ; Create a patch ; Enlarge this patch to increase BU stage 1 infections.
  clear-all
  let sink-patch-radius 2 ;increase the size of the patch here
  let sink-centre patch 0 0 ;centre of the patch 
  set sink-patches [patches in-radius sink-patch-radius] of sink-centre ; neighbouring patches
  ;set sink-patches with [abs pxcor <= 8 and abs pycor <= 8]
  ask sink-patches [ set pcolor gray ] ;set the patch to color gray
end

to setup-people
  create-popns start-people ;setting up people
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set infected? false
    set infected2? false
    set infected3? false
    set susceptible? true
    set shape "circle"
    set color brown
    set infected-time 0
    set infection2-time 0
  ]

  create-ppls start-otherPeople ; other population
   [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "circle"
    set color white
  ]
end
to assign-color  ;; turtle procedure
  if infected?
   [ set color red ]
  if infected2?
   [ set color blue ]
  if infected3?
   [ set color yellow ]
end

;; Go procedures
to go
  ask popns[ assign-color]
  ask popns[ infect_start]
  ask popns with [ infected? ]
    [  infect_two ]
  ask popns with [ infected2? ]
    [  infect_three ]
  ask popns [count-update] ; 
  ask turtles [move]

  tick
end

;; People move about at random.
to move  ;; turtle procedure
  rt random-float 360 ;the turtle turns right by 360 degrees.
  fd 1
end

to infect_start ;stage one;;
  let healthy (popns-on sink-patches) with [ susceptible? ]
   if (random-float 100 < Infection-Rate) 
  [
  ask healthy
    [
      set infected? true
      set susceptible? false
 ]
  ]
end
to infect_two ;Infect stage two = green
    if infected-time > timeA
    [set infected? false
    set infected2? true
]
end
to infect_three ;Infect stage three= yellow
  if  infection2-time > time2
   [
    set infected2? false
    set infected3? true
]
end

to count-update ; This updates the count of time in the various stages of infection or treatments
  if (infected? or infected2? or infected3?) [set infected-time infected-time + 1 ]
  if infected2? [set infection2-time infection2-time + 1 ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you can use BehaviorSpace for your export, you just formatted the code incorrectly. BehaviorSpace is much easier than trying to create your own export and managing it. So the first step is to create monitors on your interface that capture the measures that you want to output, maybe:

```
count turtles with [infected?]
```

Once you have them working (and showing whatever it is you want), then you know your syntax is correct and you simply copy the monitor's code into the output bit of the BehaviorSpace experiment.